# Remove Joomla! inline styling

Tags: css, joomla

I have a Joomla! website with a css file controlling the layouts of p tags. For some reason Joomla! thinks it's best to decide to for itself how the articles are styled by using inline styling.

Are the any ways to change settings or remove the inline styling Joomla! puts into articles?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Joomla you are using? Assuming you are on 1.5 or later & using default Tiny MCE editor,
you have following options to prevent that

1. You can switch the editor in code view & wrap your HTML code inside a
   `<div></div>` tag
2. In the administrator panel, go to extensions-> plugin manager-> TinyMCE, in parameters find 'New Lines' change it to 'br elements' instead
3. Click Artible Manager->Options->Text Filters->Scroll to SuperUsers->Change to 'none'

My advice is to go with the first option.

Comment: I just looked and see that Joomla! is wrapping all my articles in span tags with styling in. This is what I need to remove

Comment: Actually I see they're inserted by default into the editor, but is there anyway I can block this?

Comment: Is it doing that for all articles or only one in which you apply CSS via the editor? Can you provide any more details?

Comment: I need to block the span tags from being inserted, but not the p tags

Comment: What version of Joomla you are using? Also what is the default editor in joomla configuration?

Comment: As @DamienJoe asked what version of Joomla! and what editor are you using? It makes it hard to help given the wide range of editors and Joomla versions around.

Comment: 1.7 and i think it's just the default. I'm not sure.

Comment: Please log into the back end and check under Global configuration what is the default editor set to ? It must be TinyMCE if you are using default settings.

Comment: The same problem is for me. I am using Joomla 2.5. All articles are wrapped within <span> tag. It is not an option to add <div> around articles.